# Telegram bot sends updates with a long delay

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I've `Webhook` set up. My bot receives 2M messages per day. The problem is, it takes sometimes 12 hours for a message to come from telegram server to my endpoint!

I checked, when bot sends a message to telegram api, it is instant. But when the user sends a message to the bot, it takes lots of hours until my bot receives that message.

`max_connections` parameter of `Webhook` is set to maximum, 100.

What possibly is wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Telegram server will have only 100 connection to your server, you can shorten process time.

You can end webhook request in first line of code, and implementation is vary from programming language.

For instance, if you are NginX with fastcgi, it's `fastcgi_finish_request()`.